# Add DKK (Danish Krone) to Sandbox Business Account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to test my payment section of our system with paypal sandbox, but I want to test it using currency DKK. Currently it has USD and it works fine. However I am unable to find an option to add DKK and send payments in DKK.

Currently when I try to send an amount with DKK it says your business account doesn't have sufficient amount.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Log into the account you want to add the extra currency to.
- Click on the "Profile" subtab
- Go to the "My money" section and then the "Currencies" option under "More" for the "PayPal balance" category

Once you're there you can add DKK to your account. You can also do a currency balance exchange.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I get an error when I click "My money".

Error Details: Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
Cookie
/n

Comment: I used IE and it worked fine, seems like there was a problem while I was doing this using Chrome.

Thanks